# Contcatenating split strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

Hi,

I have a string of following format:

```
string arr = "a-b-c";
```

which is not constant which can be

```
"a-b-c-d";
```

I want the output as :

```
string result = "b-c"
```

or

```
"b-c-d-....";
```

I am using `string.split("-")` but not sure how to skip first element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.substring()` and `.indexOf()` as shown :-

```
var arr = "a-b-c-d";
alert(arr.substring(arr.indexOf('-') + 1));
```

```js
var arr = "a-b-c-d-e-f";
alert(arr.substring(arr.indexOf('-') + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = "a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i"; 
var res = str.slice(2);
alert(res) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to skip the first two characters, then your normal `string.split("-") to get the rest into an array.

Eg:

```
var input = "a-b-c-d-e";
var removeFirstChar = input.substring(2);
var splitChars = removeFirstChar.split("-");
```

This is assuming you always want to skip the first letter and it's hyphen.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73eqpku4/)